# Jest unit testing error: Received promise resolved instead of rejected

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nest

I am trying to test an exception being thrown, I keep getting this error. I feel like I am missing something.
I have this function:

```
  async getPreferences(eUserId: string): Promise<UserPreferences> {    

    const userPreferences = await this.userPreferencesModel.findOne({
      eUserId,
    });

    if (!userPreferences) {
      throw new NotFoundException('no results');
    }
    return userPreferences;
  }
```

This is the test I have:

```
 it('should throw an error if no userPreferences found', async () => {
      // Mock findOne result
      jest
          .spyOn(model, 'findOne')
          .mockResolvedValueOnce(throwError(new NotFoundException()));

      const result = service.getPreferences('123123');

      // Assertion
      await expect(result).rejects.toThrow('no results');
    });
```

This is the failure error I get in the console:

```
Received promise resolved instead of rejected
Resolved to value: {"_subscribe": [Function init]}

  94 |
  95 |       // Assertion
> 96 |       await expect(result).rejects.toThrow('no results');
     |             ^
  97 |     });
  98 |   });
  99 |

  at expect (../node_modules/expect/build/index.js:128:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (user-preferences/user-preferences.service.spec.ts:96:13)
```

Comment: What _is_ `throwError`? Based on your output it seems to be creating an _observable_. It's certainly not creating something where `!userPreferences` would be true, or actually throwing an error (despite the name, and which isn't the behaviour `getPreferences` is written for anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Well what are you expecting `.findOne` to actually resolve to in the case you're testing for? You test description says "no userPreferences found" and your condition is for false-y so: `undefined`? `null`?

Comment: That is not what I am doing here?
      `jest
        .spyOn(model, 'findOne')
        .mockResolvedValueOnce(throwError(new NotFoundException()));`
The findOne throws a new exeption

Comment: No, that's resolving to the result of calling whatever `throwError` is with a new error object, which as your test outcome is telling you is **not** false-y. If you were trying to test the case where the call to `.findOne` errors out (which is not actually handled by your implementation) you should mock a _rejected_ value.

Answer (score 0):

This is what eventually did:
The `mockResolvedValue` passed null, in the `service.getPreferences` I a value that I know that doesn't exist

```
it('should throw an error if no userPreferences found', async () => {
      // Mock findOne result
      jest
        .spyOn(model, 'findOne')
        .mockResolvedValue( null );

      // Assertion
      expect(service.getPreferences('-1')).rejects.toThrow('no results');
    });
```